# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el nombre de la sucursal con más pedidos de un cliente específico?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Las tablas se relacionan de esta manera:

```
table PEDIDO (
  PEDID, 
  CLIID, 
  SUCID constraint PK_PEDIDO primary key (PEDID)
);

table CLIENTE (
  CLIID, 
  constraint PK_CLIENTE primary key (CLIID)
);

table SUCURSAL (
  SUCID, 
  SUCNOMBRE, 
  constraint PK_SUCURSAL primary key (SUCID)
);
```

Por el momento llevo la siguiente consulta:

```sql
SELECT sucnombre FROM pedido INNER JOIN sucursal 
ON pedido.sucid = sucursal.sucid WHERE cliid = 31;
```

Comment: No sé mucho de oracle, pero no tendrá algo que ver las mayúsculas/minúsculas? He leído por ahí que puede ser sensible o no según configuraciones del usuario.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero me temo que no es el caso, no me genera algún error. Pero a mí consulta le falta algún tipo de condición o por el estilo para llegar al resultado que quiero :c

Comment: Ahí no te están faltando las `foreign keys`?

Comment: No amigo, la BD funciona correctamente, solo dejé los atributos que veo necesarios para hacer la consulta, los que comparten en caso de hacer Joins.

Answer (score 0):

Ya logré realizar la consulta. Por sí puede ser de ayuda para alguien :

```
SELECT sucnombre, COUNT(sucnombre) AS total
FROM pedido INNER JOIN sucursal 
ON pedido.sucid = sucursal.sucid 
WHERE cliid = v_idCliente GROUP BY sucnombre ORDER BY total 
DESC 
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Lo que hace es devolver el nombre de la sucursal(Tienda), en la cual un Cliente específico ha realizado más pedidos/compras.